# Use of base anchor size in Single Shot Multi-box detector

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I was digging in the [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) in order to check out the anchor box generations for [SSD architecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02325). In this [py file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/anchor_generators/multiple_grid_anchor_generator.py#L288) where the anchor boxes are generated on the fly, I am unable to understand the usage of `base_anchor_size`. In the corresponding paper, there is no mention of such thing. Two questions in short:

1. What is the use of `base_anchor_size` parameter? Is it important?
2. How does this parameter affect the training in the cases where the original input image is `square` in shape and the case when it isn't square?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SSD architecture there are scales for anchors which are fixed ahead, e.g. linear values across the range 0.2-0.9. These values are relative to the image size. For example, given 320x320 image, then smallest anchor (with 1:1 ratio) will be 64x64, and largest anchor will be 288x288. However, if you wish to insert to your model a larger image, e.g. 640x640, but without changing the anchor sizes (for example since these are images of far objects, so there's no need for large objects; not leaving the anchor sizes untouched allows you not to fine-tune the model on the new resolution), then you can simply have a `base_anchor_size=0.5`, meaning the anchor scales would be 0.5*[0.2-0.9] relative to the input image size.

The default value for this parameter is `[1.0, 1.0]`, meaning not having any affect.

The entries correspond to `[height, width]` **relative** to the maximal square you can fit in the image, meaning `[min(image_height,image_width),min(image_height,image_width)]`. So, if for example, your input image is VGA, i.e. 640x480, then the `base_anchor_size` is taken to be relative to `[480,480]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So,
1) If I am correct, then boxes in each layer has only one corresponding scale except for the case when there are two boxes with ar=1.
2) We don't provide base_anchor_size, so that will always default to [1.0, 1.0] in every case. Is there any piece of code that handles this ahead of time?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Yes, default is [1.0, 1.0]. I didn't understand the "ahead of time" question.

Comment: 1> Does that mean my smallest object that can be detected in 320X320 image will be of 64X64 ( at ar=1 and scale 0.2 -0.9)?  2> Can you explain once what will be the size of anchor box on layer (Conv 4-3) i.e scale=0.2 with aspect ratio of 1:2? Will it be 32X64? @netanel-sam